# Search textfile for value, then find header the value is located in

Tags: python, text

I have a textfile for some carpool information, where the driver of the car is on the top, and passengers are listed under the driver and indented, I would like to have a system that reliably finds a passenger, then it will find who's the car driver. Here is an example of what it would look like.

```
Car: Steven
    Jerry
    Elaine
    George
Car: Ross
    Rachel
    Joey
Car: Steve
    Karl
    Eric
    Red
    Ryan
```

I would like a function that takes a name like Eric and returns Steve, or takes Joey and returns Ross. The file will be much longer in actuality, but this is a snippet of what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can fit everything in memory and data looks something like

```
data = """Car: Steven
    Jerry
    Elaine
    George
Car: Ross
    Rachel
    Joey
Car: Steve
    Karl
    Eric
    Red
    Ryan
"""
```

Then you can define a function by splitting at `"Car:"`:

```
def find_driver(data, person):
    for people in [car.split() for car in data.split("Car:")[1:]]:
        if person in people:
            return people[0]
    return None
```

Then

```
find_driver(data, "Eric")
find_driver(data, "Joey")
```

returns the desired results.

Note splitting at `"Car:"` always gives a blank 0th element, so we slice past that. Then, we split the data normally (at newlines and spaces) using `car.split()`. Now we just search in order for what car a person is in.

Answer (score 0):

The following function takes the text of the file as input and produces a dictionary that maps `drivers` to their `passengers`.

```
def parse_lines(text):
    driver_to_passengers = dict()
    car_prefix = "Car: "

    current_driver = None
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        line = line.strip()

        if line == "":
            continue

        if car_prefix in line:
            driver_name = line.split(car_prefix)[-1]
            driver_to_passengers[driver_name] = set()
            current_driver = driver_name
        else:
            passenger_name = line
            driver_to_passengers[current_driver].add(passenger_name)

    return driver_to_passengers
```

To lookup a passenger, you can do the following:

```
driver_to_passenger = parse_lines(text)

passenger = "Joey"  # Example passenger name

found = False
for driver in driver_to_passengers:
    if passenger in driver_to_passengers[driver]:
        found = True
        break
```

This is a solution that compacts the space needed (the mapping is between driver and passenger) but increases the lookup time (since we are checking each driver's passengers). The lookup complexity for a single passenger is O(D) where D is the number of drivers (O(D) for iterating over the drivers, O(1) the lookup in the set).

A faster solution for your problem would be to reverse the mapping so that it now is passenger -> driver (but with this you will have some redundancy since a driver can have many passengers). The lookup complexity is reduced to O(1), and the two pieces of code above become:

```
def parse_lines(text):
    passenger_to_driver = dict()
    car_prefix = "Car: "

    current_driver = None
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        line = line.strip()

        if line == "":
            continue

        if car_prefix in line:
            driver_name = line.split(car_prefix)[-1]
            current_driver = driver_name
        else:
            passenger_name = line
            passenger_to_driver[passenger_name] = current_driver

    return passenger_to_driver
```

And the lookup:

```
passenger_to_driver = parse_lines(text)

passenger = "Joey"  # Example passenger name

driver = passenger_to_driver.get(passenger, None) # driver will be None if the passenger does not exist
```